How to use the command line to print a multiline env variable to file while preserving \n
Second Update
I'm sorry everyone, I didn't realize the difference between Makefile variables and environment variables.
In my example below I said the .env file looked like
ENV_VAR = {"example": "multi\nline\n"}

when in fact the actual example I was using was
ENV_VAR = '{"example": "multi\nline\n"}'

It seems the wrapping of single quotes was significant here (I thought they were just stripped). Without single quotes, @william purcell 's answer below does the trick
printf '%s\n' '$(MAKE_VAR)' > example.json

However, with quotes, the best solution I can see is to add the additional \ before each \n as @Barmar and @Christopher Wrogg suggested.

Update to include makefile use
I'm storing a json object with a multiline string as an environment variable and using inside a Makefile
(.env)
ENV_VAR = {"example": "multi\nline\n"}

(Makefile)
include .env
export

job:
  echo ${ENV_VAR} > example.json
  

I need to print this env variable to a file, creating a valid json file, example.json
But the above command ends up with broken json
{"example": "multi
line
"}

Likewise for printf command.
What command can I use to print this multiline env variable to a file as a single line?
Desired end result:
{"example": "multi\nline\n"}
Thanks

That's not how you assign environment variables.

Always put variables in quotes unless you have a reason not to.

Please post your actual script, this is not valid bash code.

bash doesn't convert \n to newlines automatically, except inside $'...'

Ah sorry @Barmar I've cleaned it up

ENV_VAR is not an environment variable.  It is a make variable.

Also, ENV_VAR is not multiple lines.  It is a single line that contains the string "\n", and you are relying on your particular implementation of echo to replace \n with a newline.  It will probably not behave as you want when you run on a platform where echo does not behave that way.  There is almost certainly a better way to approach the problem.

It appears that you have a .PHONY target named job whose purpose is to create a file named example.json.  Rather than creating a .PHONY target, you should just change the name of the recipe from job to example.json  (unless this is just a simplified case for the purpose of the question, I suppose).

@WilliamPursell He doesn't want echo to replace \n with newline, that's the problem he wants to fix. And I'm not aware of any "particular implementation" that does this, can you provide a reference? Some implementations have a -e option to make them do this, but none do it by default.

@barmar With bash 3.2.57, the builtin echo does the replacement. (echo "foo\nbar\n" | wc -l outputs 3)

@WilliamPursell I have 3.2.57 on my Mac, it outputs 1.

@WilliamPursell However, I get 3 from zsh.

@barmar  Interesting.  sh -c 'echo "foo\nbar\n"' gives different behavior than bash -c 'echo "foo\nbar\n"'  I wonder if this is an attempt by bash to satisfy some standard. (Both /bin/sh and /bin/bash are bash 3.2.57, but they are not links to the same executable)

@WilliamPursell Found it. [POSIX] (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) specifies that escape sequences should be processed by XSI-conformant systems. bash has a shell option xpg_echo that enables it, and it does it by default when run as sh.

In the problem you describe, there are no multi-line strings and no environment variables.  In the given example, the \n in the make variable (which in confusingly named ENV_VAR) are being replaced by newlines by your particular implementation of echo.  If you stop using echo, the problem goes away:
$ cat .env
# This is a make variable
MAKE_VAR = {"example": "multi\nline\n"}
$ cat Makefile 

include .env

example.json:
        printf '%s\n' '$(MAKE_VAR)' > example.json
$ rm -rf example.json; make
printf '%s\n' '{"example": "multi\nline\n"}' > example.json
$ cat example.json 
{"example": "multi\nline\n"}


For a dockerfile like:
FROM alpine:latest
ENV VAR='{"example": "multi\nline\n"}'
RUN apk add jq

something like:
$ echo "${VAR}" | jq -c . > example.json
$ cat example.json 
{"example":"multi\nline\n"}

would work. The -c just disables the pretty print jq does by default.
Edit:
To do this with Makefile variables:
.env
ENV_VAR = {"example": "multi\\nline\\n"}

Makefile
include .env
export

job:
        echo '${ENV_VAR}' > example.json


Escape the backslashes in .env
ENV_VAR = {"example": "multi\\nline\\n"}

and quote the variable when substituting it in the makefile
include .env
export

job:
    echo '${ENV_VAR}' > example.json

